# Creating a summation in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to calculate the number of attributable outcomes for a vector of temperatures. The equation that I need to use is:

[image]

Where j is a specific temperature, ORj is the risk ratio at temperature j, y_bar_i is the average rate of the outcome in country i , n_ij is the number of days at temperature j in country i. Here is the code I have so far but it does not work.

```
country<-c("AO", "BJ", "BU", "ET", "GN", "HT", "JO", "ML", "MW", "NG", "NP", "PH", "PK", "TJ", "TL", 
"TZ", "UG", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW")
temp<-c(20:44) 
  
for (i in country){
  outcome<-df%>%filter(country==i)
  for (j in temp){
    att_outcome=sum(abs((outcome$OR-1)/outcome$OR)*outcome$still_rate*outcome$num_days)
   }
}
```

#### Data

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AO", 
 "BJ", "BU", "ET", "GN", "HT", "JO", "ML", "MW", "NG", "NP", "PH", 
 "PK", "TJ", "TL", "TZ", "UG", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW"), class = "factor"), 
  round_tmax = c(23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28), num_days = c(7L, 
  5L, 22L, 37L, 51L, 74L), still_count = c(145, 145, 145, 145, 
   145, 145), count = c(13057L, 13057L, 13057L, 13057L, 13057L, 
   13057L), still_rate = c(0.0111051543233515, 0.0111051543233515, 
   0.0111051543233515, 0.0111051543233515, 0.0111051543233515, 
   0.0111051543233515), OR = c(1.1367209921805, 1.0527659808253, 
   0.988580432334837, 0.944599516598167, 0.91758657319397, 0.908618796371059
   )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
   ))
```

Comment: Why is there an `abs` in the code but not in the formula?

Comment: That was a mistake. It is meant to be in the equation. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group_by` `country` and perform the calculation :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(abs((OR-1)/OR)*still_rate*num_days)) -> result

result
```

Comment: I need to do the calculate for each temperature within each country and then sum the numbers together. The end result should be a sum for each temperature not each country.

Comment: Which column has temperature information? Is it `round_tmax` ? You can add that in `group_by` like `group_by(country, round_tmax)`.